# Coding Challenge 2

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

Find the element in an array which has consecutive plus or minus 1. I can achieve in O(n) time by doing a linear search. Is there any efficient way to achieve in less than O(n) time.

What I mean by plus or minus 1 is 2 consecutive number in an array will have either -1 or 1 as the difference

For example sample array inputs

Consecutive element have +1 of difference
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]

Consecutive elements have -1 of difference
arr = [ -1,-2, -3, -4 , -5, ]

Elements have either +1 or -1 of difference

arr = [-5,-4,-3,-4, -3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,3,2,1]

**Note: Array is unsorted**

Example

```
arr = [-5,-4,-3,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,2,1,2,3,4,5,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-3,-2,-1]
while i <= arr.length do 
  if num == a[i]
    puts "found"
    break
  end
  i += 1
end
```

2nd approach which in my mind is instead of starting from 0 index I have done some custom logic

```
    num = gets.to_i
    i = 0
    if (num < 0 && arr[0] < 0) || (num > 0 && arr[0] < 0)
      i = (num + arr[0].abs).abs
    elsif num < 0 && arr[0] > 0
      i = num.abs + arr[0]
    elsif num > 0 && arr[0] > 0
      i =  (num > arr[0] ? (num - arr[0]) : (arr[0] - num)) 
    end
      
    while i <= arr.length do 
      if num == a[i]
        puts "found"
        break
      end
      i += 1
    end
```

Comment: Python or Ruby? Pick one.

Comment: What do you mean by *"which has consecutive plus or minus 1"*?

Comment: @Stefan  I am comfortable with any language solution. I need an efficient algorithm

Comment: @kaya3 I have updated my question with sample input for the explanation

Comment: Can we give our answers in lisp?

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MichaelDorst  No, I guess. You can give me an answer in Ruby, Python, C, C++ and Java

Comment: O(n) is the best you can do because of two reasons: 1) Obviously, you need to read the entire array to find all occurences. 2) The length of the output can be as long as the input.

Answer (score 0):

As Nico Schertler said, O(n) is the best you can do. This is a find operation, and find operations on unsorted data are always O(n), because in the worst case they must check every element. This would be different if your data were sorted. See [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

Note also that your example code does not do what you're asking - it simply finds some number `num` in the list. Your example code is equivalent to:

```rb
arr.find { |i| i == num }
```

What you appear to be asking for is

```rb
arr.find { |i| i == num - 1 or i == num + 1 }
```

Comment: arr.find will do a linear search

Comment: @AniketShivamTiwari yes. I did not mean to imply otherwise. There is no way to do what you're asking on unsorted data without a linear search.